# Bootstrap 5 pagination border color on click

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to figure out how to change the thick light blue border that appears while the mouse button is down when clicking on a pagination number. I have tried border-color on the a element but that doesn't do it.

```
ul.pagination a.page-link:active {
  border-color: #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't remove outlines](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/) (or their visual substitutes). They have an important purpose.

It's actually a box-shadow [variable](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/pagination/#variables). But just restyle it. Don't remove it.

```
.page-link:focus {
    box-shadow: var(--bs-pagination-focus-box-shadow);
}
```

You'll want to learn how to use your browser's document inspector to discover what CSS rule is styling an element. You can force states to find :active and :hover styles, for example.